# Объявление свойства класса

Tags: классы, swift

Пример из гайда

```
class Country {
   let name: String
   let capitalCity: City!  //что конкретно здесь делает !
   init(name: String, capitalName: String) {
      self.name = name
      self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
   }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на самом деле optional тип в Swift -  простой enum c 2 значениями

```
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
```

то есть либо `.None`, либо что-то типа <T>

**знак "!" форсирует распаковку optional, то есть возвращает associatedValue из .Some(let value)**

обычный optional выглядит как

`var someValue: MyType?` - это значит, что, чтобы получить доступ к содержимому нам нужно применить распаковку **вручную**, то есть сделать либо:

```
println("\(someValue!)")
```

или распаковать и проверить через **рекомендованный способ**

```
if let value = someValue {println("\(value)")} else {println("no value")}
```

первый вариант не является безопасным и вы получите крэш с сообщением **fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None** если на самом деле в `someValue` нет никакого значения

объявление `var someValue: MyType!` говорит нам, что значение опционально, но мы разрешаем его автоматическую распаковку без лишних телодвижений, то есть мы сможем написать

```
println("someValue  \(someValue)")
```

и, даже если значения в переменной не было, мы не получим никакого крэша или сообщения, а увидим обычный результат в консоли `"someValue nil"`

вот и вся разница, просто первый вариант (со знаком "?") наиболее безопасный и перестраховочный

Answer (score 3):

Согласно документации

> These kinds of optionals are defined as implicitly unwrapped optionals. You write an implicitly unwrapped optional by placing an exclamation mark (String!) rather than a question mark (String?) after the type that you want to make optional.

Скачайте книгу:)

То есть, это делает тип "опциональным". А значит, формально, тип стает обычным указателем - у него появляется состояние, когда никуда не указывает и когда есть куда указывать. Но документация утверждает, что ничего подобного в С и ObjectiveC нет:). Насчет второго не знаю, но в чистом Си это просто указатели. В Java тоже есть. В функциональных языках это что то типа Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) говорит:

> You can think of an implicitly unwrapped optional as giving permission for the optional to be unwrapped automatically whenever it is used

Дополнительно,

> If you try to access an implicitly unwrapped optional when it does not contain a value, you will trigger a runtime error. Implicitly unwrapped optionals **should not be used** when there is a possibility of a variable becoming `nil` at a later point. Always use a normal optional type if you need to check for a nil value during the lifetime of a variable.

То есть это распакованная ссылка, которая логически не должна быть `nil`. Ближайший аналог в других языках — reference в C++.